# payU money android SDK bypass Login/SignUp screen is possible?

Tags: android, payumoney

I don't want the payU money Login/SignUp screen during the payment checkout in android application if any one have done please share your knowledge, how to by pass the signup or login Screen, Directly allow the customer to pay their payment with credit/debit card or net banking. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is now not possible.. according to new SDK as on March, 2017

Look for function "**check_login()**" in **SdkHomeActivityNew.class** which opens up the *initLayout()* but only when the user is already logged-in otherwise Login screen would surface **SdkLoginSignUpActivity.class**

Their habit of shifting codebase on github is really irritating..